# How can I make a SwiftUI View observe changes in a computed property that's an array?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

In a SwiftUI App using Core Data, and I have a `FetchRequest` in the top level View:

```
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Student.fetchRequest())
    private var students: FetchedResults<Student>
```

And then I have some computed property arrays that I derive from that `FetchResults`:

```
    private var year7Students: [Student] {
        return students.filter { $0.grade == 7 }
    }

    private var year8Students: [Student] {
        return students.filter { $0.grade == 8 }
    }
    ...
```

If I make a `View` with a `List` over the `students: FetchedResults`, like this:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section("All Students") {
                    ForEach(students) { student in
                        NavigationLink(destination: StudentDetailView(student: student) {
                            StudentCardView(student: student)
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
         }
     }
```

then it shows all the students, and when I update one (via the detail View), the View automatically updates.

But when I do the same using `year7Students: [Student]` etc, like this:

```
            List {
                Section("Year 7 Students") {
                    ForEach(year7Students) { student in
                        NavigationLink(destination: StudentDetailView(student: student) {
                            StudentCardView(student: student)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section("Year 8 Students") {
                    ForEach(year8Students) { student in
                        NavigationLink(destination: StudentDetailView(student: student) {
                            StudentCardView(student: student)
                        }
                    }
                }
                ...
             }
```

then it shows the relevant students in each list, but updates made in the Detail view do not result in the data in the List being updated when the nav stack pops back to this view, which I'm guessing means a View refresh isn't being triggered.

What can I do to make the Views based on the computed property arrays reactive to when the objects in the underlying `students` property changes?
Or what different approach can I use to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Are you showing both 7 and 8 grade students at the same time or one at a time?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: At the same time. So there are multiple lists on the page. When navigating down into a detail view, changing an entity, then returning to the top of the nav stack, the data in those lists doesn't refresh.

Comment: I've updated the description to show how the arrays are used in the View.

Comment: When I first posted this, I left out the detail that the student rows in the List view were rendered by another view struct. Once I realised that was a difference between my code and this question, I experiment and found that was the source of the issue.

Comment: Note that you could use a SectionedFetchRequest and have everything in one list.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, @JoakimDanielson. I didn't know about `SectionedFetchRequest`. It seems perfect for the trivial example I put in this SO question, but my real filters in my real project are more complex than just one attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out my problem here was nothing to do with the arrays.

The problem was in `StudentCardView`, where I had:

```
    let student: Student
```

There was nothing in this View that told it to update itself based on changes in the Student object.

Changing it to:

```
    @ObservedObject var student: Student
```

made everything start working. So it seems arrays that are computed properties based off `FetchResults` are observed by the View without doing any extra work. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Faster than filtering by Standard Library is filtering directly in Core Data with a predicate.

`FetchedResults` has an `nsPredicate` property. When set it updates the associated property

A simple solution is to add a `State` property `grade`

```
@State private var grade = 0
```

In the `onChange` modifier of the view change the predicate. You can define a value (here 0) to show all records

```
.onChange(of: grade) { newGrade in
    students.nsPredicate = newGrade == 0 
    ? nil 
    : NSPredicate(format: "grade = %ld", newGrade) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I'm showing multiple of these lists on the screen at the same time, so all the students are shown on the screen, in separate lists by grade. My assumption was that it would be more efficient to pull them all out with one, un-predicated `FetchRequest`, then build filtered views in memory. Your suggestion would require 6x `FetchRequest`s in the view, each with a different predicate. I think it would work, I'm just worried it isn't the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach, using the `filter` directly in the `List`, instead of
creating separate computed variables,
like in this example code:

```
struct Student: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var grade: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var gradeFilter: Int = 0
    
    // for testing
    @State var students = [Student(name: "student-1", grade: 1),
                           Student(name: "student-2", grade: 7),
                           Student(name: "student-3", grade: 7),
                           Student(name: "student-4", grade: 8)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(students.filter {$0.grade == gradeFilter}) { student in
                Text(student.name)
            }
            HStack {
                Button("set filter to 7") {  gradeFilter = 7 }
                Spacer()
                Button("set filter to 8") {  gradeFilter = 8 }
            }
            HStack {
                Button("add a student with grade 7") {
                    students.append(Student(name: "student-7", grade: 7))
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("add a student with grade 8") {
                    students.append(Student(name: "student-5", grade: 8))
                }
            }
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        .padding()
    }
    
}
```

Note, a computed var can be used, and when a new `student` is added somewhere, the `View` will be updated,
as long as the `students` are `State` or `StateObject/ObservedObject` (CoreData objects are ObservedObject),
that is, is under observation by the view.

Similarly, if something else, like `@State var gradeFilter` is changed,
the View will be updated.

For example:

```
 var filteredStudents: [Student] {
     students.filter { $0.grade == gradeFilter }
 }
 
 //...
 List(filteredStudents) { student in
     Text(student.name)
 }
 //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Following from my comment I did some code test. You need the filters to return as a FetchedResults type. They are then objects in the managed object context and updates will be picked up. To do this you need to run another request that applies an NSPredicate as the filter. This will not actually load again from the "database" as values should already be cached within the context.

You could use the main FetchRequest but also use another variable as the one that filters in case you use the full list elsewhere at the same time.

```
var studentsByGrade: @FetchRequest( sortDescriptors: [] , predicate: nil) private var subSet: FetchedResults<Item>

func getStudentsByGrade(_ grade: String) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "grade == %@" , grade )
    studentsByGrade.nsPredicate == predicate
}
```

This will update the predicate (filter) and cause it to refresh (which will be cached so quick). The link to the Apple documentation on FetchRequest.predicate - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest/configuration/nspredicate

The strings are a bit clunky as at the heart core data seems to rely on a lot of objc and strings...